# QT HTML not rendering clickable link

Tags: html, qt

Complete HTML beginner here.

I have this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd">
<html><head><meta name="qrichtext" content="1" /><style type="text/css">
p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }
</style></head><body style=" font-family:'.SF NS Text'; font-size:13pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;">
<p style=" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:12px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;"><a name="tex2html381"></a><a href="https://cms.mpi.univie.ac.at/vasp/vasp/About_this_document.html"><span style=" text-decoration: underline; color:#0000ff;">A</span></a><span style=" text-decoration: underline; color:#0000ff;">bout this document ...</span></p></body></html>
```

And to my knowledge, when displayed it should produce a clickable link. However it does not and I cannot figure out why - I've tried changing the `<span>`'s and messing with a few other parts. If something sounds weird, some of it was auto generated from a QT QTextBrowser.

Comment: You mean that the problem is only the A is clickable, or something else?

Comment: By the way, the HTML syntax you're using was officially declared deprecated in 1999; is that what QT generates?

Comment: @MrLister Hah. I never noticed, as I can't see a color difference between the link and the non link. Ideally I'd like it all to be clickable. I moved the last `</a>` to after the last `</span>` and it works exactly as I wanted. Thank you.

Comment: @MrLister QT 5.8, yes.

Answer (score 0):

The link is currently only wrapped around the beginning "A".
The code produces a link, just not on the whole sentence.

Restructure your code and you will see it much better!